# Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPageAdapter - Xamarin.Forms.Label does not inherit from either Xamarin.Forms.Page or Xamarin.Forms.ContentView

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have added new View and ViewModel in my project. When I navigate to new page I am getting exception. No matter what I keep in xaml but I am getting this exception.

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label does not inherit from either Xamarin.Forms.Page or Xamarin.Forms.ContentView.'
```

This is my `.xaml` code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Project.ViewsFor.SubscriptionsView"
             Title="StackLayout Spacing demo">
    <StackLayout Margin="20"
                 Spacing="0">
        <Label Text="Primary colors" />
        <BoxView Color="Red" />
        <BoxView Color="Purple" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

`.xaml.cs` file

```
using Bite2.ViewModels.ViewFor;
using System;

namespace Project.ViewsFor
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SubscriptionsView : ContentPage
    {
        public SubscriptionsView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel constructor is not hitting before that application is getting crashed. I am using naming convention same as existing like MyPageView and MyPageViewModel. I have added newly added page in App.xaml.cs file as below along with existing viewmodels

```
 _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
 _container.PerRequest<SubscriptionsViewModel>()
```

Code for navigation -baseviewmodel.cs Line 1099

```
public void GoToNewPageAsync()
{
    _navigationService.For<SubscriptionsViewModel>().Navigate();
}
```

This stacktrace I got

```
[AppCenterCrashes] Unhandled Exception from source=AndroidEnvironment
[AppCenterCrashes] System.NotSupportedException: Xamarin.Forms.Label does not inherit from either Xamarin.Forms.Page or Xamarin.Forms.ContentView.
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPageAdapter.PushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Element view, System.Object parameter, System.Boolean animated) [0x00045] in <0e15cf5b914344a49663668aa30dc0cd>:0 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPageAdapter.NavigateToViewModelAsync (System.Type viewModelType, System.Object parameter, System.Boolean animated) [0x0001d] in <0e15cf5b914344a49663668aa30dc0cd>:0 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPageAdapter.NavigateToViewModelAsync[T] (System.Object parameter, System.Boolean animated) [0x0000f] in <0e15cf5b914344a49663668aa30dc0cd>:0 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Caliburn.Micro.Xamarin.Forms.NavigateHelper`1[TViewModel].Navigate (System.Boolean animated) [0x00013] in <0e15cf5b914344a49663668aa30dc0cd>:0 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Project.ViewModels.BaseViewModel.GoToSubscriptionsAsync () [0x00001] in C:\Users\Path\Project\ViewModels\BaseViewModel.cs:1510 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Project.ViewModels.BaseViewModel.SelectMenuItem (Project.Models.SettingsItem leftMenuItem) [0x00103] in C:\Users\Path\Project\ViewModels\BaseViewModel.cs:1598 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Project.ViewModels.BaseViewModel.<LeftMenuVisibillity>b__127_0 (System.Object s, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) [0x0000f] in C:\Users\Path\Projec\ViewModels\BaseViewModel.cs:1099 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-29/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84 
[AppCenterCrashes]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.43(intptr,intptr)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: does the stack trace show which line is causing the error?

Comment: @Jason - Please check my updated question.

Comment: What is code at, and also show a few lines before, this line `Project.ViewModels.BaseViewModel.GoToSubscriptionsAsync () [0x00001] in C:\Users\Path\Project\ViewModels\BaseViewModel.cs:1510`

Comment: `left_Menu = new LeftMenu(_leftMenuItems, Version);
                _leftMenuPopup.ItemSelected += async (object s, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) =>
                {

                    SelectedLeftMenuItem((SettingsItem)e.SelectedItem);
                    await OffLeftMenuAsync);
                };`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - find the code in above comment..

Comment: My best guess is that something in those lines, maybe `e.SelectedItem` is a `Label`, but is passed to a method that expects a Xamarin `Page` or `ContentView`, hence the error message. Use breakpoint or Debug.WriteLine to find out what is a Label, then read doc or examples of methods to find out what is expecting a Page or ContentView. The fix might be to "wrap" some XAML inside a `<ContentView>`. If you find what Label it is, that would be a clue about what needs to be wrapped. Maybe just wrap the Label in a ContentView.

Comment: My best guess is that something in those lines, maybe `e.SelectedItem` is a `Label`, but is passed to a method that expects a Xamarin `Page` or `ContentView`, hence the error message. Use breakpoint or Debug.WriteLine to find what line there sees Label, then read doc or examples of methods to find out what is expecting a Page or ContentView. The fix might be to "wrap" some XAML inside a `<ContentView>`. Maybe need `<ContentView><StackLayout><Label ..> ... </StackLayout> </ContentView>`. Just guessing.

Comment: Something must be coded wrong, either in `GoToSubscriptionsAsync `, or in the value that `SelectMenuItem ` passes to `GoToSubscriptionsAsync `. Shouldn't be working with a `Label` there. Can't "navigate to a new page", given a Label. If your goal is to navigate to a new page, then shouldn't the object passed be the new page?